# How to auto-approve the task form

Tags: auto-approve

When we start an approval process the user should need not to click on the approve button on task form, it should auto approve.

Does any one know how to perform this?

Answer (score 0):

If the task form is not needed, then perhaps the process should not create a task...

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your explaination here, can you enlight my by extending your answer? Thanks!

Comment: if the process is going to "auto approve a task" then why create the task in the first place?